# Could someone guide me on how to efficiently save multiple records simultaneously using the FilteredSelectMultiple widget within a Django admin form?

Tags: django

I want to save multiple record at a time using admin form.

**admin.py**

```
class  QFE_BENG_LANGUAGE_ModelAdmin(QFE_BaseModelAdmin):
    form = adminModelFilterForm
    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        # debug(request.POST,"request")
        form = super().get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
        selected_question_ids = request.POST.getlist('question_id')
        selected_exam_id = request.POST.get('exam_id')
        # Create QUESTION_FOR_EXAM instances for each selected_question_id
        if obj is None:
            for question_id in selected_question_ids:
                check = QUESTION_FOR_EXAM.objects.filter(exam_id__id = selected_exam_id, question_id__id=question_id)
                if not check:
                    question_instance = QUESTION_FOR_EXAM.objects.create(
                        exam_id_id=selected_exam_id,
                        question_id_id=question_id
                    )
        return form
        
    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == 'question_id':
            kwargs['queryset'] = BENG_LANGUAGE.objects.filter(topi_name__id=1)
            kwargs['widget'] = admin.widgets.FilteredSelectMultiple('Question ID', is_stacked=False)
            kwargs['required'] = False
        return super().formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)

admin.site.register(Q_FOR_EXAM_BENG_LANGUAGE,QFE_BENG_LANGUAGE_ModelAdmin)
```

**form.py**

```
class adminModelFilterForm(forms.ModelForm):
    subject_name = forms.ChoiceField(choices=select_subject,required=False) 

    class Meta:
        model = QUESTION_FOR_EXAM
        fields = ('subject_name', 'exam_id', 'question_id')
```

**Model.py**

```
class QUESTION_FOR_EXAM(models.Model):
    exam_id = models.ForeignKey(EXAM, blank=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Exam ID")
    question_id = models.ForeignKey(BENG_LANGUAGE,blank=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="QUESTION ID")
```

When I click on save button it shows:
[image]

**After successfully saving a record in the QUESTION_FOR_EXAM table, how can I redirect the user to initiate a new insertion or navigate to another page?**